# Настройка приема почты на VPS (Debian)

Tags: debian, dns, sendmail

Добрый день,У меня есть VPS на нем хостится несколько сайтов (у регистратора прописана A запись), Почта работает через google и pdd.yandex.ru.Нужно настроить один домен так, чтобы почта приходила непосредственно на этот VPS (все лишь одному юзеру). В какую сторону копать?

1. Для отправки почты стоит Exim4
2. Как настроить MX зону?
3. Какой soft нужен для получения почты?
4. В общем ткните носом куда копать, пожалуйста, только не глубоко)))

Answer (score 1):

Если используете google aps почту в нём то у гугла есть инструкция что делать.
почта@вашдомен.com
в вашдомен.com создать MX запись с почтовыми серверами гугла к примеру:

```
mx 10 mail.google.commx 20 mail2.google.commx 30 mail3.google.com
```

Адреса для примера гугл даст вам свои.
После этого письма в почтовом ящике будет гугл как принимать так и отправлять.
Чтобы забирать почту с этоо ящика необходимо в почтовом сервере на VPS указать smtp сервер.

```
smtp.google.comлогин почта@вашдомен.comпароль %вашпароль%
```

Почтовый сервер должен поддерживать TSL и шифрование. пор 587 кажется.фраза

> чтобы почта приходила непосредственнона этот VPS

Немного не точна, потому что почта будет приходить к гуглу а с вашего VPS почтовым сервером вы просто по smtp будете её забирать/отправлять.

Вопросы?

Comment: Что делать с почтой google apps я знаю. Мне требовались рекомендации, советы по настройке своего сервера. Сейчас я это понимаю...Когда задавал вопрос не совсем понимал)))

Comment: рад был помочь.